# Bash script double quote

Tags: bash

I have an issue with a bash script and need to ask for some help. The script is following:

```
#!/bin/bash
config_options="CFLAGS=\"-Wall -pipe\""
./configure --prefix=$PWD/install $config_options
```

If I use run this script, I got the error "unrecognized option -pipe". However, if I directly use the following command, it works.

```
./configure --prefix=$PWD/install CFLAGS="-Wall -pipe"
```

My understanding is that this command and the bash script are exactly the same, since I already put escape character \ before ". I don't know why this script gave an error.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Recommended reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The quotes in `config_options` do not protect the whitespace between `-Wall` and `-pipe`; they are treated as literal charters in the string. As a result, `configure` sees two separate arguments `CFLAGS="-Wall` and `-pipe"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass-in command line options in a string variable like this. You can use BASH array instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
config_options=(CFLAGS="-Wall -pipe")
./configure --prefix=$PWD/install "${config_options[@]}"
```